# Return the key from database query in Clojure

Tags: database, clojure, return, key-value

I'm very new to Clojure and would like to know how to simply return the value when I query the database in clojure

I've defined a function foo like below:

```
(defn get-foo []
    (log/info "Getting foo from the database")
    (let [query "select FOO from BAR where FOO = 'test'"
        results (jdbc/query (db-connection) [query])]
        (log/info "Results: " results)
        (log/info "Foo: " (get :foo results)
        (log/info "String: " (apply str results))))
```

What I see in the logs:

```
Results: ({:foo test})
Foo: nil
String: {:foo "test"}
```

I would like to be able to somehow return only `test`, without the value attached to it like in a clob, ideally, sort of like:
`(log/info "Foo: " results)` would return:

```
Foo: test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(log/info "Foo: " (:foo (first results)))
```

returns:

```
Foo: test
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the most optimized way to go about this, but it works for me :)

Comment: A database query is generally going to return a sequence of hash maps -- one hash map for each row in the result set.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense - for one result, there's only going to be one sequence, get the first of that, and get the value from key - thank you!